# Azure Function - Event Hub Trigger stopped

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I've got an Azure Function app in production on an event hub trigger, it's low throughput with the function typically only being triggered once daily. It's running on an S1 plan at the moment and has a few other functions such as timer triggered and HTTP triggered.

It's been running fine but today it stopped being triggered by new messages until I restarted the app. All other functions were working just fine and responding to their associated triggers.

I've look through App Insights and there are no reported errors or issues, it's just not doing anything.

Has anyone else had this issue or know of what may be causing it?

Comment: Just for info, I've confirmed that there are indeed messages on the event hub

Comment: do you have always on enable ? you should contact the azure team for this kind of issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - is your App Service has **Always On** enabled?

Second thing - have you tried to test your trigger locally, so you can be sure, that there are no issues with your Event Hub?

Personally, I faced such issues when Event Host Processor implemented in EventHubTrigger was losing a lease because of additional processor introduced. It is also possible, that since it faces a low throughput, it lost a lease and for some reason was not able to renew it:

> As an instance of EventProcessorHost starts it will acquire as many
>   leases as possible and begin reading events. As the leases draw near
>   expiration EventProcessorHost will attempt to renew them by placing a
>   reservation. If the lease is available for renewal the processor
>   continues reading, but if it is not the reader is closed and
>   CloseAsync is called - this is a good time to perform any final
>   cleanup for that partition.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2015/01/21/event-processor-host-best-practices-part-2/

Nonetheless, it is worth to contact the support to make sure there were no other issues.

Comment: I've checked and AlwaysOn is enabled, the function was tested locally as well so I know that's all working as expected. It had been running daily for a while beforehand as well. The lease renewal sounds like it could be more of a possibility given what I'm seeing, just a shame there doesn't appear to be any error information around it. The function is set to run as a singleton so there shouldn't be more than 1 reader but it sounds worthy of more investigation.

Comment: How did you ensure, that it will be run as singleton?

Comment: Using the singleton attribute
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton

Comment: I am afraid it does not work for Azure Functions - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/912 ;) It works only for WebJobs.

Comment: Seems like it does work for pre compiled C# functions (which I'm using), and I'm seeing singleton behaviour, but I'm feeling like this needs further investigation

Comment: "Seeing singleton behavior" -- you are being mislead by an _artifact_ of how the functions runtime works, not by a design feature. Under low volume (e.g., when you are testing), all of your function invocations are likely to be served by the same host process, which has not restarted, so `static` members will _look_ like they are globally unique to _all_ invocations, but they will not be under any significant load, where invocations will start spreading across multiple hosts & processes.

Comment: @Dusty that is very important nuance that I have never encountered in any documentation. Do you have a reference handy for this behavior?

Comment: @gabe It's not explicitly documented anywhere official, it's more the nature of how functions work ... they are very intentionally designed to scale across virtual and physical hardware in an environment and process agnostic way. The closest to citing sources as I can get is the link below, where you'll find a comment from Chris Anderson, the PM for Azure Functions, explaining this dynamic. It essentially boils down to `static` resources are helpful for [read-only] caching of data, but can't be trusted for synchronizing/sharing/mutating it. https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/158